# How do I set a relative path for an .SO file?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, configure

This is my error:

> 06-29 16:52:37.729  24144-24144/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.my.app, PID: 24144
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "build/obj/local/armeabi/libavformat.so" needed by
>   "libFFmpegWrapper.so"; caused by library
>   "build/obj/local/armeabi/libavformat.so" not found

build/obj/local/armeabi/libavformat.so looks wrong to me. The code worked with an earlier build of ffmpeg - so I suspect it's something to do with the way I build ffmpeg.

The libavformat.so file is in the APK where I'd expect it to be.

This is my build script for ffmpeg:

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=/Users/eran/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-12/arch-arm
PREFIX=/usr/local

function build_one
{
  ./configure --target-os=android --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --pkg-config=./fake-pkg-config \
  --enable-cross-compile \
  --cpu=armv7-a \
  --enable-shared \
  --disable-static \
  --disable-asm \
  --arch=arm \
  --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
  --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --disable-stripping \
  --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
  --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
  --disable-nonfree \
  --disable-version3 \
  --disable-everything \
  --enable-gpl \
  --disable-doc \
  --enable-avresample \
  --disable-demuxer=rtsp \
  --disable-muxer=rtsp \
  --disable-ffplay \
  --disable-ffserver \
  --enable-ffmpeg \
  --disable-ffprobe \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-encoder=libx264 \
  --enable-decoder=h264 \
  --disable-protocol=rtp \
  --enable-hwaccels \
  --enable-zlib \
  --disable-devices \
  --disable-avdevice \
  --extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/include -fPIC -DANDROID -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -march=armv7-a" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8" \
  --extra-cxxflags='-Wno-multichar -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti'
  make -j4 install
}

build_one
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by loading all required libraries rather than letting the system try and find them itself.

```
System.loadLibrary("x264");
System.loadLibrary("avutil");
System.loadLibrary("avcodec");
System.loadLibrary("avformat");
System.loadLibrary("swresample");
System.loadLibrary("swscale");
System.loadLibrary("FFmpegWrapper");
```